# How does the scipy.weave.inline command know if code was previously compiled?

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I tried using scipy.weave.inline today and it works fine. 
After running the program the first time, it knows that the C code was previously compiled and runs much faster afterwards. I would like to know how it knows and where the compiled code exists?

Answer (score 1):

`weave` has various caching strategies, as can be seen [from the source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/weave/inline_tools.py#L361): a local cache that's just a dictionary keyed by the source code, and then falling back to [a function catalog](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/weave/catalog.py) that has its own cache or saves things on disk.